# I'm getting "Unauthenticated" message with a valid token in Laravel Passport using Flutter

Tags: laravel, flutter, request, laravel-passport

I built a Web Service using Laravel Passport for authentication, when I register a user, it generates an access token successfully, but when I am trying to retrieve the user info, I get unauthenticated.

The interesting part is that making the social sign up with Postman, the access token generated works, but when I make the sign up with the app, the access token is not valid.

This is my request code on my mobile app:

```
Future<Map> socialSignIn(UserSocialAuth userSocialAuth) async {
    final String _socialPath = '/social_auth';
    Future<Map> socialSignInResponse;
    try {
      socialSignInResponse = postRequest(_socialPath, userSocialAuth.toJson());
    } catch (error, stackTrace) {
      print("Exception ocurred: $error  stackTrace: $stackTrace");
      socialSignInResponse = jsonDecode('{"exception": $error, "stackTrace": $stackTrace}');
    }
    return socialSignInResponse;
}

/// POST Request
Future<Map> postRequest(String serviceName, Map data) async {
    Map responseData = {};
    FormData formData = FormData.fromMap(data);
    _dio.options.connectTimeout = connectTimeout;
    _dio.options.receiveTimeout = receiveTimeout;
    try {
      Response response = await _dio.post(
        _endpoint + '$serviceName',
        data: formData,
        options: Options(
          headers: {
            'Authorization': await getAccessToken(),
            'Accept': 'application/json'
          }
        )
      );
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        responseData = response.data;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // An error was received
      responseData = {
        'error': 'No se pudo conectar con el servidor de $_appName',
        'exception': e.toString()
      };
    }
    return responseData;
}
```

And this is the request for the user data using access token:

```
Future<Map> currentUser(String accessToken) async {
    final String _currentUserPath = '/user';
    Future<Map> userDataResponse;
    try {
      userDataResponse = getRequest(_currentUserPath);
    } catch (error, stackTrace) {
      print("Exception ocurred: $error  stackTrace: $stackTrace");
      userDataResponse = jsonDecode('{"exception": $error, "stackTrace": $stackTrace}');
    }
    return userDataResponse;
  }

/// GET Request
Future<Map> getRequest(String serviceName) async {
    Map responseData = {};
    _dio.options.connectTimeout = connectTimeout;
    _dio.options.receiveTimeout = receiveTimeout;
    try {
      Response response = await _dio.get(
        _endpoint + '$serviceName',
        options: Options(
          headers: {
            'Authorization': await getAccessToken(),
            'Accept': 'application/json'
          }
        ));

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        responseData = response.data;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // An error was received
      responseData = {
        'error': 'No se pudo conectar con el servidor de $_appName',
        'exception': e.toString()
      };
    }
    return responseData;
}
```

I do not know why works with postman and not with the app.

I save the access token with SharedPreferences like this:

```
/// ----------------------------------------------------------
/// Method that returns the token from Shared Preferences
/// ----------------------------------------------------------
Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();

Future<String> getAccessToken() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;
    String _authorizationToken;

    if (prefs.getString(_accessTokenKey) != null) {
      _authorizationToken = 'Bearer ' + prefs.getString(_accessTokenKey);
    }

    return _authorizationToken;
  }

/// ----------------------------------------------------------
/// Method that saves the token in Shared Preferences
/// ----------------------------------------------------------
Future<bool> setAccessToken(String token) async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;

    return prefs.setString(_accessTokenKey, token);
}
```

Comment: can you show where u r savings token and how u r adding token in header.?

Comment: @KamleshPaul I update my question

Comment: now it seems right

Comment: is it solved .?